# Exporting all data from data views

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to export all data from the core data views (ListSubscribers, Bounce, Unsubscribed, etc.) so that they can be brought into another system, but there doesn't seem to be any straightforward way to do this.

For views like Unsubscribed and Bounce, I've been able to set up Data Extract automations from the enterprise account which pulls from all business units, but trying to "Export Subscribers" using the same method just yields me a data-less csv with column headers and nothing else, regardless of the time period. I've tried building data extensions at both the enterprise and business unit levels, and automations to populate them from ListSubscribers, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you use _ListSubscribers, you should specify the ListID by using `WHERE ListId = “123”` in the query.

Otherwise use _Subscribers data view or ent._Subscribers if you are not in the parent account. The ListID can be found in the Properties tab in All Subscribers or your subscriber list.

Answer (score 0):

Do you send from lists? If you mostly send from data extensions, you might want to try the _Subscribers data view instead? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5

Create a DE with the fields in the help article and then SELECT * FROM _Subscribers and add in any WHERE clauses you need?